# Google API analytics PHP per day

Tags: php, api, analytics

I am using the google-api-php-client, installed through composer, v2.0.
I need to extract the data per day/week/month etc.
However, I am only getting the totals.

I am probably missing one property, but I can't find anywhere what it should be.

This is the request I am using

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('Login to my app');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);


function getReport($analytics, $profileId) {
  $VIEW_ID = $profileId;

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  $dateRange2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange2->setStartDate("14daysAgo");
  $dateRange2->setEndDate("7daysAgo");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("Sessions");
  $new_users = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $new_users->setExpression("ga:newUsers");
  $new_users->setAlias("New users");
  $organic = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $organic->setExpression("ga:organicSearches");
  $organic->setAlias("Organic results");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges(array($dateRange,$dateRange2));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions, $new_users, $organic));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

And this returns only the totals of the dateranges that I specified.

I hope you can help me find the missing property or what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 2.0 library (I should probably update), but you need to add the `ga:date` dimension to the report request to have it grouped by date. You can use the [Dimensions and Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) to mess with the metrics to see what data you should be getting.

Comment: @aynber Thank you! That was really the part that was missing I added these lines to the request and am now getting the correct data. `$date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension(); $date->setName("ga:date"); $request->setDimensions(array($date));` If you make an answer of this, I will mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `ga:date` dimensions to group the results by date. You can find the full list of metrics and dimensions, and play with the data, by using Google Analytics [Dimensions and Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/). As you mentioned in your comment, you would add this to your code:

```
$date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension(); 
$date->setName("ga:date"); 
$request->setDimensions(array($date));
```